# How to modify values of a template html inside a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an Ajax call that gets different description, and url address of a video:

```
function TraerInstructivos() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/Instructivo/Instructivos.aspx") %>' + '/TraerInstructivos',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            var res = JSON.parse(response.d);
            $.each(res, function (i, item) {
                DibujarVideo(item);
            });
        },
        error: function (response) {
            alert("Error");
        }
    });
};
```

Now `DibujarVideo` is the method that will grab the template I have in my ascx, make a copy and then append it. This is the HTML of the ascx:

```
<div id="Videos">

</div>

<template id="video-elem">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <font id="video-desc" size="3"></font>
            <br />
            <br />
            <p><a id="video-ref" class="btn btn-secondary" href="#" role="button">Mira el Video &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <hr />
</template>
```

Right now, the method that copies the template html looks like this:

```
function DibujarVideo(video) {
    var elemACrear = $("#video-elem").html();

    $(elemACrear).find("#video-ref").attr("href", video.DireccionVideo);

    console.log(elemACrear);

    $("#Videos").append(elemACrear);

}
```

What I see in the console log, and the page is that the value of href is not changing, but If I save this in a variable I see the changes for example:

```
var elem = $(elemACrear).find("#video-ref").attr("href", video.DireccionVideo);
```

So I reckon is not the same changing/manipulating the DOM tree in a page vs in a variable.

How can I change that href inside my **elemACrear** variable?

Im learning jQuery, every help appreciated.

Comment: the reason you have this behaviour is because `.html()` returns a String with HTML code inside, not an actual DOM object. Passing this string inside `$()` makes jQuery build a DOM object from it, but if you don't get it back in a variable, you still have the original string (`.attr` modified the built DOM object but not the original string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've already diagnosed and solved the issue without following the logic through. You simply need to provide the jQuery object you create in the `elem` variable to the `append()` call, like this:

```
function DibujarVideo(video) {
  var elemACrear = $("#video-elem").html();
  var $elem = $(elemACrear);
  $elem.find("#video-ref").attr("href", video.DireccionVideo);
  $("#Videos").append($elem);
}
```

Comment: Ok, what I see is that, elem is only the a tag. Is there any chance to grab everything in the template and only change the href of the a tag inside of it?

Comment: You're right - my mistake. I updated the answer for you

Comment: Ah amazing, I see, so I put all the html inside a variable. Now my last question is, what does the $ stands when you create a variable? in this example $elem, instead of var elem?. Marked as answer.

Comment: The `$` is just a naming convention. It denotes that the variable holds a jQuery object. It has not other special behaviour.

Comment: Amazing, thank you, now is gonna be easier knowing these two things.